# STM32H7 as SPI slave only

Tags: stm32, spi

I'm moving my project code from STM32F407 to STM32H743 and I am stuck with SPI. First of all STM32H743 has more registers and it also lacks some of them like RXONLY register in CR1.
What I'm trying to do is receive 19 bytes from the master. The master is a complete device and I can't control it. The clock speed of the master is around 20 nanoseconds. My previous project in STM32F407 is catching the data perfectly.

STM32H743 CODE: INIT FUNCTIONS:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 24;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES_RXONLY;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 0x0;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPolarity = SPI_NSS_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.FifoThreshold = SPI_FIFO_THRESHOLD_01DATA;
  hspi1.Init.TxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
  hspi1.Init.RxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
  hspi1.Init.MasterSSIdleness = SPI_MASTER_SS_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
  hspi1.Init.MasterInterDataIdleness = SPI_MASTER_INTERDATA_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
  hspi1.Init.MasterReceiverAutoSusp = SPI_MASTER_RX_AUTOSUSP_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.MasterKeepIOState = SPI_MASTER_KEEP_IO_STATE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.IOSwap = SPI_IO_SWAP_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

STM32H743 READ SPI FUNCTION:

```
static void ReadSpi(void)        
{                  
  RxSPI1 = 0;
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  GPIOA->MODER = 0xAA809910;
  SPI1->CFG2 |= SPI_CFG2_SSM;
  SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
  RxCounter = 0;
  while(RxCounter <20){
    
    while (!(hspi1.Instance->SR  & SPI_FLAG_RXP))    
         ;

    RxSPI = hspi1.Instance->RXDR;                    
        
    // now you have 8 SPI clock cycles to do something with the data
    if (RxSPI != 0xFF )
    {
      RxTable[RxCounter++] = RxSPI;      
    }
  }
         
  return;
}
```

while F4 is working fine, H7 is just stuck here:

> while (!(hspi1.Instance->SR  & SPI_FLAG_RXP))

What am I missing?

Comment: The H7 SPI far more complex than F4. You should read the H7 reference manual how to use it. It supports doing the transactions for you if you configure it to transfer something as per the manual.

Comment: Since you're setting CFG2_SSM for software-controlled Slave-Select, you probably need to do something with CR1_SSI.

Comment: @Justme i have read manual and cant understand the case what am i doing wrong. The thins is that in f4 it works perfect. As i understand you is that just changing registers for h7 will not work, then thi is more complex then i tought

Comment: @brhans i just tried to set same spi registers from F4 to H7

Comment: @KlimDuda Yes the two completely different STM32 MCUs have two completely separate SPI peripherals. Using code that works on F4 is guaranteed not to work on H7 because it is completely different SPI peripheral. You need to write your custom SPI driver for H7 registers from scratch. Or use the HAL. Or use the HAL as reference when writing your code.

Comment: @Justme i have tried hal as well, it didnt catch anything either :( basiclly what i need its just wait when SR instance will catch the data and read it from RXDR flag, sounds easy on paper, but why its hard to accomlish i have no idea. Can you advice please where can be a problem, im ok to using HAL